# 10 bit/color channel support

Tags: color

I am in need of 10 bit colour/channel (30 bit in total).
Everything in my workflow supports 10 bit colour/channel: DSLR, Eizo 276, D700 in my Mac Pro (late 2013). Unfortunately OSX 10.9.8 is still on 8 Bit/channel.

Can any body tell me a work around?

Comment: You might want to update your question since OS X 10.9.8 does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know OS X does not support 10 bits channels.

Here is a [blog article](http://blog.conradchavez.com/2013/10/22/os-x-10-9-mavericks-will-adobe-software-work/) which talks about it : **Nope**. 
[Another site](http://nativedigital.co.uk/site/2013/10/os-x-mavericks-compatibility-is-10-bit-finally-here-for-the-mac/) says they thought Mavericks would bring 10bits channels, but **nope**. 
4 month later, [same site, still **nope**](http://nativedigital.co.uk/site/2014/02/achieving-10-bit-display/).

Comment: One line answers are discouraged.

Comment: See my updates.